# Insert to remote server MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I'd like to insert data in a trigger to a remote mssql 2005 server from my local mssql 2005 server.

I have a table Syr; I creates a trigger (AFTER INSERT) to detect if something has been added to it.
I'd like to copy that data to another remote server's same table. 
My problem is if I just execute the insert statement(which is very simple, uses static data just for testing) in a normal query, it succeeded; I can even select from the remote server.
but when I put this simple insert into a trigger block: "unable to begin a distributed transaction"

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_SyrInserted
ON [DBProba].[dbo].[Syr]
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN

INSERT INTO [RemoteSrv].[DBProba].[dbo].[Syr] (SyrId, SyrNm ) VALUES (15000734, 'valami')
END
```

Solved:

- Set the DTC authentication to None
- I run into an error "nested transaction cannot be executed because XACT_ABORT is OFF" so added a line before insert statement: SET XACT_ABORT ON; I dont know what "nested" I have done with an simple insert but fine...

Comment: DTC turned on at both ends?...

Comment: Try exec `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` in a "normal query". A query that is executed within the context of a trigger is automatically wrapped in a transaction. If there are any distributed queries in the trigger code, the transaction is promoted to a distributed transaction automatically.

Comment: Distributed Transaction Control is running on both server. Firewalls are down. Allowed DTC access, allowed inbound, allowed out..

Comment: Tried enclose the insert statement with "begin distributed transaction" and "commit transaction" failed with same error. Select statement also failed with this way, but if I leave 'distributed' keyword select works insert not. The other sql server is running on a virtualbox machine. Checked the Windows event viewer. No warning or error for mssql or msdtc.

Comment: I changed the authentication from mutual to none on both sides. Then I got this  "A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF."
when i tried to insert as distributed transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case the update statement opens a local transaction and the insert statement also opens a transaction with the remote server which will be the case for the distributed transaction.

In order to make this work, you have to start the DTC http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817064

To know more about distributed transactions, you can check the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you people. I set to authentication to none(DTC properties) and also added a line into the trigger the SET XACT_ABORT ON before the insert, and looks like it is working.